# How to count nonzero occurrences based on another variable in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

```
Date      Precipitation
20010101  0
20010102  10
20010103  5
20010104  3
20010105  0
...
20011231  0
```

I have dataset showing precipitation (in) per each day in the year 2001. The date variable is in `YYYYMMDD` format. I want to calculate how many times it precipitated each month. In other words, I need the number of times the precipitation value is not 0 per each month.

I am a beginner python learner and don’t quite know how to tell the program to output the count per each month without having to do it individually.

The code I have below does not work because I’m not sure how to tell the program the Date variable is in `YYYYMMDD` format.

```
Precip_Count= Date[(Precipitation !=0)]
```

Is there a way to do this by only using NumPy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, convert `Date` column to `datetime` using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and specify the format of your datetime string [`Datetime format code`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), then use [`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) to find non-zero values, groupby month and take the sum using [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum)

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%Y%M%d")
df['Precipitation'].ne(0).groupby(df.Date.dt.month).sum()

Date
1    3
...
12   0
Name: Precipitation, dtype: int64
```

OR using [`Series.dt.to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) here.

```
df['Precipitation'].ne(0).groupby(df.Date.dt.to_period('M')).sum()

Date
2001-01    3
...
2001-12    0
Freq: M, Name: Precipitation, dtype: int64
```

If you want index as DatetimeIndex use [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html)

```
df['Precipitation'].ne(0).groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).sum()

Date
2001-01-31    3
...
2001-12-31    0
Freq: M, Name: Precipitation, dtype: int64
```

---

<sub>The output is calculated from `df` mentioned in the question.</sub>